# Ionic firebase Google auth signinwithpopup blank screen

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-signin

I have an Ionic Angular Capacitor App, and I use Firebase to handle authentication.

I wanted to add Google SignIn and it's working on browser but none on mobile (Android).

I get a popup with my google accounts list but when I click on one, the app try a redirect to an url : https://******.firebaseapp.com/_/auth/handler?state ..........................................

but I get a blank page and no redirection.

Someone has already fixed this issue ?

Thanks

```
return this.signInWithProvider(new GoogleAuthProvider().setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" }))

signInWithProvider(provider) {
return this.angularFireAuth
  .signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('You have been successfully logged in!');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/main', { replaceUrl: true })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorKeyTrad = error.message.split('/')[1].replace(').', '');
    this.toaster.presentErrorToast("ERROR.AUTHENTICATION." + errorKeyTrad, 15000)
    console.log(errorKeyTrad);
  });
```

}

Comment: I am getting exactly the same issue with both google and facebook. I have searched whole internet and there is no solution anywhere. It seems social login with Firebase auth has become impossible in 2023.

Comment: The problem is, the platforms google and facebook (and possibly others) think that the redirect url is insecure but it has https and despite adding SHA1 fingerprints, the error does not go away.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no direct solution to this problem at present, but you can easily overcome the issue with a the following workaround:

1. Get auth token of the platform using some other plugin. I was able to get auth token for google and facebook using following plugins:

https://github.com/CodetrixStudio/CapacitorGoogleAuth

https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login

2. Once you have the token using above plugins, create credential and use signInWithCredential method.

   ```
   const googleUser = await GoogleAuth.signIn() as any;

   const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.authentication.idToken);
   ```

   And for Facebook:

   ```
    const FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = ['email','public_profile'];

           const result: FacebookLoginResponse = await FacebookLogin.login({ permissions: FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS });

       if (result.accessToken) {
           const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);
   ```
3. Now, you can use signInWithCredential to login into firebase auth:

   ```
   const result = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
   console.log('Login successful: ', result.user);
   ```

This works perfectly on both ios and android.